# Using JQ to grep boolean and array at the same time

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm pretty new with Jq and have some trouble starting.

I am making a new bash script that gets a .json file from URL and it needs to grep multiple values but save only domains to a new file as output.

In this example, I would need to grep all companies with identity==true, but save only the domains from the array that matches identity=true to a new file.

I have tried almost everything but to no luck.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "companies": [
        {
            "name": "CompanyOne",
            "url": "https://companyone.com",
            "identity": false,
            "domains": [
                "companyone.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CompanyTwo",
            "url": "https://companytwotwo.com",
            "identity": true,
            "domains": [
                "companytwo.com",
                "companytwotwo.net"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
companytwo.com
companytwotwo.net
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible - your JSON snippet is not valid JSON, and you have not shown the output you expect.  It would also probably be a good idea to show at least one of the attempts you've made.  Since the `re` in `grep` refers to regular expressions, it would probably be better to write "select" if no regex matching is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just use `select` like this:

```
cat data.json | jq -r '.companies[] | select(.identity) | .domains[]' > yourfile.txt
```

Try it out https://jqplay.org/s/NKD3-BkXLj

Comment: Good stuff. I needed to add select(.identity == true) and everything finally worked properly. 

Thanks a lot!